# what should I put before the forEach loop that should loop through a function? javascript

Tags: javascript, function, api, foreach

Im doing a project in javascript with API from restCountries https://restcountries.com/#rest-countries-v3-vs-v31
I want to create a forEach loop where I can loop through the result and create whats in the function showCountry() But I dont know what I should put before in the forEach loop? What can be relevant? Thanks in Advance!

```
const countries = document.querySelector('.countries')
const lang = document.getElementById('search').value
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')

function getCountries(){
    const search = document.querySelector('.search').value
    fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/lang/${search}`,{
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
    
    ??.forEach(api=> {
        showCountry(api)
    })

}
    
function showCountry(data){
    const country = document.createElement('div')
    country.classList.add('country')
    country.innerHTML =
    `<div class="country-img">
        <img src="${data.flag}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="country-details">
        <h5 class="countryName">${data.name}</h5>
        <p><strong>Population:</strong>${data.population}</p>
        <p><strong>SubRegion:</strong>${data.subregion}</p>
        <p><strong>Capital:</strong>${data.capital}</p>
        <p class="languageName"><strong>Language:</strong>${data.lang}</p>
    </div>`

    countries.appendChild(country)
}
```

Html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Search country by language!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="controls">
            <i class="bx bx-search"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search by language.." id="search" class="search">
        </div>
        <button id="btn" onclick="getCountries()">Search Country</button>
    </div>
    <div class="countries">
        
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** (with new async/await keywords)

```js
async function getCountries(){
    const search = document.querySelector('.search').value;
    const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/lang/${search}`,{
        method: "GET",
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    data.forEach(api=> {
        showCountry(api)
    })

}
```

**Solution** (with `then`)

```js
function getCountries(){
    const search = document.querySelector('.search').value
    fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/lang/${search}`,{
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => 
       data.forEach(api=> {
         showCountry(api)
       })
    );    
}
```

Answer for [object][object] issue mentioned in the comment -

Your API response `data` has different properties than what you are using in your code.

Updated method -

```js
  
function showCountry(data){
    const country = document.createElement('div')
    country.classList.add('country')
    country.innerHTML =
    `<div class="country-img">
        <img src="${data?.flags?.png}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="country-details">
        <h5 class="countryName">${data?.name?.common}</h5>
        <p><strong>Population:</strong>${data?.population}</p>
        <p><strong>SubRegion:</strong>${data?.subregion}</p>
        <p><strong>Capital:</strong>${data?.capital}</p>
        <p class="languageName"><strong>Language:</strong>${data?.languages?.eng}</p>
    </div>`

    countries.appendChild(country)
}
```

Comment: "async" should precede "function".

Comment: Missed it, updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! the fetch and search works super! But I get NO FOUND 404 now and object object where the flag and name should be. Is this anything you can see what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated the answer, please try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/lang/${search}`,{
    method: "GET",
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(api => {
        showCountry(api)
      }
    });
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for/loop`, creating a DOM element, adding HTML to it, and attaching it to the DOM, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a little simpler to use. You're already using a template string to make the HTML so we can fit that right in.

Note: you should look at the JSON response to understand how it's put together so you can write your HTML properly. For example `data.name` will not work because `name` is an *object* containing a `common` property, and an `official` property, so you need to get one of those values instead.

I've used [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) in this example as it's a little easier to break up the code, and a little easier to read. Also, I've only used a couple of examples in the HTML - `flag`, `common` name, and `population`.

```js
// Cache the countries element
const countries = document.querySelector('.countries');

// Fetch the data. If there's an error in the response throw it,
// otherwise return the parsed JSON
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all');
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${res.statusText}`);
  return res.json();
}

// Accepts the parsed JSON it `map` over that array
// of objects, destructures the properties that will be
// used in the HTML, and returns the HTML for that
// object using a template string. Once the iteration is
// complete join the array of strings `map` returns
// into one single string
function buildCountries(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {

    const {
      name: { common },
      population,
      flag
    } = obj;

    return `
      <section class="country">
        <h4>${flag} ${common}</h4>
        <p>${population}</p>
      </section>
    `;

  }).join('');
}

// Get the data, get the HTML, and then add the HTML
async function main() {
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    const html = buildCountries(data);
    countries.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}

main();
```

```css
.country { background-color: #efefef; padding: 0.25em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.country:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 0.25em; }
h4 { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="countries"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)